# How to remotely run a program on the Jetson TK1 using Nsight Eclipse

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, cuda, gpu

I've finished the setup of my jetson tk1 eval board and I've started to setup my Nsight Eclipse to remotely run my programs on the Jetson board.

I've created a CUDA C project in Eclipse and completed the setup and connected my board to my eclipse.

When I build the sample CUDA file locally on eclipse it's working fine but when I try to run on the remote board, I get this output :

```
echo $PWD'>'
/bin/sh -c "cd \"/home/ubuntu\";export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"/usr/local/cuda-     
6.0/lib\":\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH};\"/home/ubuntu/test\"";exit
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ echo $PWD'>'
/home/ubuntu>
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ /bin/sh -c "cd \"/home/ubuntu\";export   
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\" /usr/local/cuda- 
6.0/lib\":\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH};\"/home/ubuntu/test\"";exit
/home/ubuntu/test: 1: /home/ubuntu/test: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
logout
```

From the last line of output, it seems like it's an executable format error. Does anyone ever encountered something similar? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Are you sure the error is not `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the answer. The version of Eclipse I had wasn't able to correctly compile my cuda file into the ARMv7 format. So I was always uploading an x64_86 format executable file.

My solution was to create a bash script that transfers the cuda file and compile it directly on the board when I launch the run sequence from eclipse.

In the end it took a bit of programming to make things work but it's now compiling and executing correctly on the remote board.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I meet the same problem. I solve these problem by delete the whole workspace and generate a new one. You can have a try.